# Expression for children entitySet parent properties

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

I need to build an expression that will work on a parent entity properties so will do the following:

```
IQueryable<Children> allChildren = from e in context.Children select e;

IQueryable<Children> filter = allChildren.Where(x => x.Parent.Name == "Value");
```

I created an expression of type `Expression.Lambda<Func<Parent, bool>>` for that but I cannot use it on Children 'Where', no suitable overload. How to accomplish this?
Children are entity set of a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that nested expression is what I need here and it's working fine

Comment: Can you provide an example please?